# Stopping the registarion on invalid input:JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a registration form with date of birth as one of the fields, I have written a function for future date which has to be invalid. But when the user puts a future date it still submits the form, although alert is being made to the user.

This is the function for alert, and its working fine.

```
var user_birth_year=document.getElementById("birth_year").value;
var user_birth_month=document.getElementById("birth_month").value;
var user_birth_day=document.getElementById("birth_day").value;

var userDate = new Date(user_birth_year,user_birth_month-1,user_birth_day);

var currentDate = new Date();
var res="Invalid date";
if(currentDate.getTime() < userDate.getTime() ) {
  document.getElementById('registererror').innerHTML = "<span class='errorMsg'>"+res+"</span>";
  document.getElementById('registererror').style.display = 'block';
} else {
  document.getElementById('registererror').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: some html code where you use it pls. Where is your return of the function?

Answer (score 6):

Usually to stop the submit of a form, you need to return false on the form submit event.

Comment: thats fine, if there is nothing in the field then do not return false. if there is something in the field, check that it validates, if it does not validate, return false. I'll add some code to my answer to elaborate if you like